# Can't get Django/Postgres app settings working on Heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm making a Django app with the Two Scoops of Django template. Getting this Heroku error, are my Postgres production settings off?

- OperationalError at /
  could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
- Exception Location: `/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py`
- foreman start works fine
- Procfile: `web: python www_dev/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`
- local.py settings:

  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
          'NAME': 'www',
          'USER': 'amyrlam',
          'PASSWORD': '***',
          'HOST': 'localhost',
          'PORT': '5432',
      }
  }
- production.py settings: commented out local settings from above, added standard Heroku Django stuff:

  import dj_database_url
  DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

  SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

  import os
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))
  STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
  )
- UPDATE: production settings, tried changing:

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])

(named my Heroku color URL to DATABASE_URL, same link in heroku config)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable? I believe what is happening is this: by default Django is using your `local.py` settings, which is why it's trying to connect on localhost.

To make Django detect and use your `production.py` settings, you need to do the following:

`heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.production`

This will make Django load your production.py settings when you're on Heroku :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me. In wsgi.py and manage.py I've explicitly referred to DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as myprojectname.settings.production. To run locally, I run `python manage.py runserver --settings=myprojectname.settings.local`. Does that seem like an ok workflow?

Comment: Yes, that's totally fine! That's the best practice :)