# Django. Using multiple settings files with Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, settings

I am trying to follow the advice of the book "Two Scoops of Django" and although it is a really good book, I think it this section is unclear. 
So, I split my settings file and created a folder like this:

```
settings/
 __init__.py
 base.py (allmost everything there)
 local.py (dev. specific settings)
 production.py (settings for Heroku)
```

most of the settings are in the base.py file

in local.py I have this:

```
# settings/local.py
from .base import *
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
INSTALLED_APPS += ("debug_toolbar", "django_extensions", "south",)
```

in production.py I have this:

```
from .base import *
INSTALLED_APPS += ("gunicorn",)
```

When I run locally:

```
python manage.py runserver 7000 --settings=appname.settings.local
python manage.py runserver 7000 --settings=appname.settings.production
```

everything works fine.

But when I push changes to Heroku, I get the log:

```
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app

 raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

So, I guess Heroku is not finding my settings files, I don't know how to fix this (it might be very simple).

*Two Scoops of Django is kind of ironic here, it writes "Platform as Service - See section 25.2" and then in that section it just writes "read Platform Documentation"* : /

Comment: Does this solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674128/cant-get-django-postgres-app-settings-working-on-heroku?rq=1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After you have logged into heroku with heroku login you can check your configs by running: 
`heroku config`.
 If you dont see a `SECRET_KEY` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` you can set them by running:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='secret_key_goes_here'
```

and

```
heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings.production
```

Finally, make sure that you have the following syntax inside of your production setting file:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

The above intstructions are for the following project structure

```
-myproject
  -app1
  -app2
  -mysite
    -settings
      __init__.py
      base.py
      dev.py
      production.py
-manage.py
-Pipfile
-Procfile
-requirements.txt
```

Comment: dont forget to remove the space after config:

Answer (score 9):

You can use the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to specify a default settings module:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

On local Linux machine:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.local
```

On Heroku:

```
heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.production
```

Comment: Hi Soytoise. I did that and I also included `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','appname.settings.production')` in the wsgi file as I understood from the documentation you posted. But I get the error *ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.production' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings.production* :/

Comment: @alejoss try `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.local` where `project` is the name of your project.