# Python (django) environment variables

Tags: python, django, heroku, foreman, env

I am working with django and virtualenvwrapper. My objective is to remove all sensitive information from the settings file per the 12Factor app suggestions (http://12factor.net) and ultimately deploy to heroku. When testing this locally, to achieve this, I have created a .env file with different variable values like SECRET_KEY. I went to my virtualenv directory and added the following line to the postactivate script:

```
source .env
```

Whenever I start my virtual env for a project aka workon project_name, the environment variables from .env are available if I echo from the terminal

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However when I try to access those variables from python they are unavailable

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
>>>
```

What is the correct way for python to access the environment variables stored in a .env file?

.env file:

```
WEB_CONCURRENCY=2
SECRET_KEY='XXXXXXXXXXXX'
DEBUG=True
```

Comment: Did you `export` the `SECRET_KEY` or just define `SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxx`?

Comment: I defined the SECRET_KEY inside .env and am sourcing the .env file every time I run "workon project_name". I never explicitly exported it or anything inside the .env file.

Comment: No, what I meant is what did you write in your `.env` file. Did you have `export SECRET_KEY=xxxxx` or `SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxx`?

Comment: @alexolivas Please show your .env file.

Comment: `SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxx`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are defining it in your current shell by doing `SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxx`, but when you open up a python shell, it's running in a sub process and you lost the environment variable in that shell. `export` will make the variable available in sub process as well.

You should have:

```
export SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxxx
```

In your `.env` file to make it work.

**Edit:**

From what I read from your links, that's just a normal linux shell environment variable. But django needs to have `SECRET_KEY` as a python constant in the settings. Linux environment variables and python variables are two different things, so defining a env variable `SECRET_KEY` doesn't let django recognize `settings.SECRET_KEY`. You should still consider using separate settings file, which is mostly recommended.

Comment: I've been following heroku's django deployment guide and they are using an env file for this, the example is a bit incomplete which is where I'm stuck.  Plus I think its cleaner to maintain 1 settings files even if they all inherit from the same base_settings for all the common settings. Using export worked but now I'm more confused than when I started since you're suggesting that's not good practice.

Comment: Oh, I don't know enough about heroku, maybe I was wrong. I will remove my suggestion about settings file because heroku might have some trick to make it work with `.env` file. But I think you should understand why you need `export`. In case you still want to use multiple settings file, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071489/django-using-multiple-settings-files-with-heroku

Comment: BTW, I'm still interested in where did you find the guide though.

Comment: That makes two of us, I just started learning about heroku a couple days ago. I was using multiple settings files when my app was hosted at webfaction. This tutorial is for [django on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) and this one is for the [local config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) that heroku uses and how to run your code in development.

Comment: Also, I do understand the need for export. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't think the guide for django setup mentions anything related to environment variable, so I guess heroku doesn't have anything different than a normal linux machine.